# Download of some JavaScript timesout after 2 mins on Question pages

Tags: bug, status-norepro, performance

When I browse to a question page, one of the requests doesn't complete as times out after 2 minutes. Looking at the source it looks like it's a `<script>`. This blocks/delays some of the JavaScript on the page. The rest of the page renders properly and I can see all the questions & answers, but the browser 'busy' spinner is still there.

For instance for question: [Is SVN global ignore recursive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599489/is-svn-global-ignore-recursive)

The request to: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7599489/ivc/c30c times out after 2 mins.

I happens on all my browsers (IE8, FF 7.01, Chrome 14).

Note: We have a very strict proxy here which tries to strip out ads, spam and social networking sites.

**EDIT**: I have attached a screenshot from Firebug of the offending request:

[image]

Comment: Can't repro, page loads fine. Try without your proxy.

Comment: No repro. I can't even find the file you mentioned, can you please point us to the exact resource? Screenshots of Firebug (or similar, showing the timed out request) are welcome, too.

Comment: FYI, it's not even a JavaScript file, so it not loading should not cause any issues with the interface.

Comment: lunbocks - As I said below, all JavaScript execution is blocked until the 2 minutes is up. Meaning that I can't for instance comment on something until it's timed out. Also - the syntax highlighting and the orange background highlighting the current answer remains that colour until the 2 minutes are up.

Answer (score 2):

That request returns a HTTP 204 No Content. While that's perfectly legal, some broken proxies are known to choke on that. My guess is that's what happens in your environment.

Comment: I think that's most likely the case. Because it's trying to download a `<script>`  JavaScript is blocked until it times out.